# how to import Emerson DeltaV fhx file into tables in any database

Tags: java, xml, database, file-conversion, date-conversion

Emerson DeltaV database keeps the data in fhx file. Its kind of raw text file. You can see the sample fhx file structure as below (although its incomplete one). Normally its quite big in size and can go upto 1 GB text file in size. My requirement is to Get this fhx file from Emerson DeltaV server and store this in our local database into tabular format. So that we can run the sql query and find the desired data as required.

Here some idea is may be we can convert this fhx file to xml first then there is way to import that xml into database. Another option is may be there is some way we can import fhx file directly into database into tabular format. I would like to tell you here that i am looking the solution in Java preferbaly. Please help me guys if you have some idea on this.

```
/* "28-Sep-2022 11:50:42" */

SCHEMA
 user="MCS" time=1664391017/* "28-Sep-2022 11:50:17" */
{
  /* Database last updated on "29-Jul-2019 18:07:54" */
  VERSION=1564448874/* "29-Jul-2019 18:07:54" */
  MAJOR_VERSION=14
  MINOR_VERSION=3
  MAINTENANCE_VERSION=1
  BUILD_VERSION=7282
  BUILD_ID="xr"
  VERSION_STR="14.3.1.7282.xr"
  ONLINE_UPGRADE=F
}
LOCALE
 user="MCS" time=1664391017/* "28-Sep-2022 11:50:17" */
{
  LOCALE="English_United States.1252"
}
ENUMERATION_SET NAME="_OFF_ON" FIXED=F
 user="Administrator" time=1599522168/* "07-Sep-2020 16:42:48" */
{
  DESCRIPTION="Discrete Output OFF/ON"
  CATEGORY="Named Sets/MCS"
  ENTRY VALUE=0 NAME="OFF" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=1 NAME="ON" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=255 NAME="UNDEFINED" { SELECTABLE=F }
  DEFAULT_VALUE=0
}
ENUMERATION_SET NAME="_EM_STATE" FIXED=F
 user="Administrator" time=1623680856/* "14-Jun-2021 07:27:36" */
{
  DESCRIPTION="State Driven EM Commands"
  CATEGORY="Named Sets/MCS"
  ENTRY VALUE=0 NAME="HOLD" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=1 NAME="CMD1" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=2 NAME="CMD2" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=3 NAME="CMD3" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=4 NAME="CMD4" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=5 NAME="CMD5" { }
  ENTRY VALUE=255 NAME="Undefined" { }
  DEFAULT_VALUE=0
}
PLANT_AREA NAME="MCS_PLANT" INDEX=1
 user="MCS" time=1656377878/* "27-Jun-2022 17:57:58" */
{
  SEQUENCE_NUMBER=1
}
FUNCTION_BLOCK_TEMPLATE NAME="AI"
 user="DeltaVSystem" time=1564457649/* "29-Jul-2019 20:34:09" */ OOB=T
{
  DESCRIPTION="Analog Input"
}
```

Comment: The fhx file is XML so no conversion is necessary.  It is very easy in Powershell to read this xml and the write to a SQL Server Database.  I have done this lots of times.  I would start by designing the database and create the tables.  The parsing of xml is simple.  The entire task is only a couple of hours.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you so much for your reply. But by mistake i pasted the xml file above which i got after converting fhx file to xml by some program in C++. I am updating the correct fhx file now and its not like xml actually. It looks like json. Please give your thought again after checking the updated fhx file.

Comment: I've been learning Powershell which is great.  I would recommend using SQL Server Management Studio for the database which you can download the Express version for free and is much quicker then processing a text file that is 1GB.  You can parse the JSON in powershell with ConvertFrom-Json (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?force_isolation=true) and then store and query with Invoke-Sqlcmd

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your input, i will surely have a look on SQL server managment studio and will try to download free version. But i am mainly concern about this fhx file. As you can see above it just look like json but actually its not even json file. So i am wondering is there any way i can convert this fhx file to xml or json and then can use SQL server management to dump those file in database in tabular format. Have you ever heard or work on this Emerson DeltaV fhx file before?

Comment: Can you still use the c++ program?  It would be easier to upload the xml than the fhx.

Comment: yes i also think the same that xml or json would be easier to import into any database rather than fhx itself. About C++ i am not using it and i do not have knowledge on it. I am mainly into Java language. This C++ conversion program is written by my client which is very old and now they want to convert it into Java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252575/discussion-between-purushottam-kumar-and-jdweng).